# Video size for my home header

Tags: video-quality

i would like to buy a footage video for my home header page, but i don't know what is the good size to have a good rendering and not a too long loading.

Web 640x360 25 fps Photo-JPEG
Web 640x360 25 fps H.264
SD 720x486 29.97 fps NTSC
SD 720x576 25 fps PAL
HD 1280x720 25p Photo-JPEG

thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go for the HD 1280x720 and get it compressed using Handbrake or ffmpeg or similar to H.264 video in MP4.